# How can I control objects of another process?

Tags: c#, object, process, architecture, client-server

I have two applications to access the API of my client-server system:

1. GUI to hand in credentials and to give the number of clients that should be created.
2. "BackEndInteractor" that actually creates a client object and interacts with the server that has been selected in the GUI.
   After connecting to the server, each client has the mission to search for the same document in order to find out how the feedback delay by the server increases with the number of clients.

My problem is that with the way I designed things, I cannot seperate the connection of the client to the server and the searching for documents.

What I want to do is to enable the GUI user to have two buttons "Connect Clients" and "Search with all Clients Simultaneously" to work around a mechanism that prevents too many clients from being instantiated at the same time.
**Accordingly, I need the GUI to have access to the Client objects that are created in the first step and that are afterwards responsible for searching for documents.**
Putting the creation of Client objects 'into' the GUI did not work because that caused the problem of only being able to have one Client ( = one process which is the GUI.exe itself).

Please consider that I am a beginner and feel free to propose different system designs if it is not possible to "keep track of the objects of another process".

**1.: GUI**

Essentially, this is what happens here:

```
private void button_ConnectClients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartExe(clientcount, serverHostname, username, pw, searchstring);
}
```

```
public void StartExe(int clientcount, string serverHostname, string username, string pw, string searchstring)
{
    // Start Client processes via console app "BackEndInteractor.exe" with args[]
    for (int i = 1; i <= clientcount; i++)
    {
        Process.Start(filename,
                    String.Concat(                      
                        serverHostname, " ",
                        username, " ",
                        pw, " ",
                        searchstring)
                    );
    }
}
```

**2. "BackEndInteractor"**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // First, store the args in local attributes
    DemoClientManager demoClientManager = new DemoClientManager(args);

    // Now connect to the server
    demoClientManager.StartClientConnection();
}
```

```
public void StartClientConnection() 
{
    // start stopwatch sw1 to measure the time to create a client
    client = Interactor.CreateClient(hostname, username, pw);
    // stop stopwatch sw1 and calculate difference from sw1.start() to sw1.stop()
    
    Interactor.SearchForDoc(client, searchstring);
}
```

```
public Client CreateClient(string hostname, string username, string pw)
{
    // do some stuff to get the correct config
    
    var client = new Client(config, hostname);
    var initResult = client.Init(username, pw);
    
    return client;
}
```

```
public async void SearchForDoc(Client client, string searchstring)
{
    // start stopwatch sw2 to measure the time to search for a document
    var foundIds = await Client.Document.FilterDocumentIds(documentTitle, searchstring);    
    // stop stopwatch sw2 and calculate difference from sw2.start() to sw2.stop()
    
    if (foundIds != null) 
    {
        // start stopwatch sw3 to measure the time to load a document
        var doc = await Client.Document.LoadDocument(foundIds[0]);
        // stop stopwatch sw3 and calculate difference from sw3.start() to sw3.stop()
    }
    
    // clear memory
    Client.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need some sort of Inter Process Communication (IPC). If I had to do that, I'd probably try some sort of MessageQueue. Seems sufficient for the purpose.